# PHP I have a problem adding additional elements to existing objects using two Arrays with same length

Tags: php, arrays

After 25+ Stack Overflow searches and over an hour (for what I thought would be a simple answer) I must throw in the towel and ask. All I want to do is add additional elements to existing objects in one array from the contents of another array with the same length.

I have tried (from various SO posts) the following approaches:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    array_push($upper_lower[$i], $candidate_results[$i]);
}

$output = array_intersect($upper_lower, $candidate_results);
$output = $upper_lower+$candidate_results;
array_push($upper_lower, ...$candidate_results);
```

... and received no errors but the outcome was always different than I need. Mostly, the various methods returned the second array appended to the END of the first array but some added the second array to the first correctly but left the new element in its own object (e.g., {"E_Jones": 6}) (again, not what I want).

Here is Array1:

```
$upper_lower = [
    {
        "factor": "Factor1",
        "Upper_Boundary": 8,
        "Lower_Boundary": 5,
        "D_Allen": 8
    },
    {
        "factor": "Factor2",
        "Upper_Boundary": 7,
        "Lower_Boundary": 4,
        "D_Allen": 4
    },
    {
        "factor": "Factor3",
        "Upper_Boundary": 9,
        "Lower_Boundary": 7,
        "D_Allen": 7
    },
    {
        "factor": "Factor4",
        "Upper_Boundary": 8,
        "Lower_Boundary": 6,
        "D_Allen": 8
    }
]
```

Here is Array2:

```
$candidate_results = [
    {
        "E_Jones": 5
    },
    {
        "E_Jones": 9
    },
    {
        "E_Jones": 3
    },
    {
        "E_Jones": 6
    }
]
```

I want the following from the example arrays:

```
$combinedarrays = [
    {
        "factor": "Factor1",
        "Upper_Boundary": 8,
        "Lower_Boundary": 5,
        "D_Allen": 8,
        "E_Jones": 5
    },
    {
        "factor": "Factor2",
        "Upper_Boundary": 7,
        "Lower_Boundary": 4,
        "D_Allen": 4,
        "E_Jones": 9
    },
    {
        "factor": "Factor3",
        "Upper_Boundary": 9,
        "Lower_Boundary": 7,
        "D_Allen": 7,
        "E_Jones": 3
    },
    {
        "factor": "Factor4",
        "Upper_Boundary": 8,
        "Lower_Boundary": 6,
        "D_Allen": 8,
        "E_Jones": 6
    }
]
```

Comment: _"Here is Array1:"_ - that's not valid PHP code to begin with. (Yes, I am aware it would constitute valid JSON, if given in string form.)

Comment: I apologize. I do not know how to create the correct terms/format for this question. I am trying to copy from DevTools to give as much information as I know.

Comment: `var_export` is a good tool to create PHP code that can be used for the variable initialization, or you could have made this an example that actually parses the JSON to create the corresponding arrays.

Comment: Either way, it's a pretty easy to solve "problem", here is one way: https://3v4l.org/tIjb7

Comment: @CBroe That WORKED! Thank you. Should you make this an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One easy way to do this:

```
for($i=0, $c=count($upper_lower); $i<$c; ++$i) {
    $key = array_key_first($candidate_results[$i]);
    $upper_lower[$i][$key] = $candidate_results[$i][$key];
}
```

`array_key_first` gets you the `E_Jones` key from the sub-arrays of your second array (assuming that was *not* always the same static value, but could be dynamic) - which you need to *set* the value under that key, in your first array.

(If the inner arrays in your second array could ever contain more than one entry you want to add - then you would have to *loop* over them, instead of accessing just the first one.)

Comment: Works great! Thank you! And, you are right ... the "E_Jones" is dynamic and will change. Thanks for catching that!